# Foundation 5 - Navbar Centralizing

Tags: zurb-foundation, navbar

Morning,

I wanted to find out if its possible to make a change to the current foundation 5 navbar without breaking it for mobile and desktop views.

basically the current one sits the left text/image to the far left and the nav menu to the far right, which is great when the design is across the entire page, but if the content is centralized in the middle sort of like the normal 960 web layouts, it looks a bit weird at times.

is it possible to have the left image/text and nav menu links centralized in the center like it would be seen if it was in a 960px wrapper.

this all ofc without stopping the responsiveness of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what your are trying to accomplish is to center a top-bar navigation within a row.

If that's the case then you can use `<div class="contain-to-grid">` to keep your top-bar within your grid layout and something like `<div class="small-9 small-centered columns">` to center the row that the top-bar is in. I created a codepen example for you to look at here: http://cdpn.io/jJhyn.

The classes mentioned above are all part of Foundation so you will not be affecting the responsiveness of your design.

For a complete list of the options available to customize the top-bar see the [Zurb Foundation Top Bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) documentation.

If I have misunderstood your question let me know, and code is always appreciated.

I hope that helps.

---

EDIT: 02/13/2014

I was looking into another issue when I stumbled upon this, [How to center top-bar nav?](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1230-how-to-center-top-bar-nav). It center's the buttons/links within the top-bar, not the top bar itself. They page they used as an example is [Mister Dutch](http://www.misterdutch.nl/new/default). I updated the codepen above to reflect what I found on the Foundation Forum.

Again, if I have misunderstood your question let me know.